# Double Summation index change

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, index-notation

The generating function of the Bessel function can be written as:

$$g_{(x,t)} =\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\sum_{s=0}^{\infty} (-1)^s (\frac{x} {2})^{r+s} \frac{t^{r-s}} {r!s!} $$

Changing the summation index $r$ to $n=r-s$ leads to:

$$g_{(x,t)} =\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}[\sum_{s=n}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^s } {(n+s)!s!} (\frac{x} {2})^{n+2s}] t^n$$

How the new summation bounds are obtained? I can understand the variables and factorials' new form in this new summation index, but can not figure out the range of the converted double summation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure about this? r-s can be arbitrarily large both positively and negatively, so I don't know if this converges for any t.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. You can see Arfken 7th Edition pp. 644